# Gradle version on Terminal different from Project Gradle version

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to run Crashylistics `gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease` feature & It's Complaining that my Gradle version is to low,

Now checking my gradle-wrapper.properties file, I have this below:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

But when I check my Terminal Gradle version with `gradle -v` I get this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.8.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-06-21 07:53:06 UTC
Revision:     0abdea078047b12df42e7750ccba34d69b516a22

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64
```

Why is my Gradle version on my terminal different from the one in my Project?

Please how can update my Gradle version on Terminal to latest one? I'm confused.

: I have tried `brew upgrade gradle` It doesn't work

Comment: I think you need to use `./gradlew` in order to use the wrapped gradle version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling the following command in your terminal:

```
gradle -v
```

it will run the gradle binary installed in your system, not the gradle binary in your Android project.

For your project, you need to run the `gradlew` file in your root project directory by calling:

```
./gradlew -v
```

Do not forget the `./`. That's the most important part. Using `./` means that you want to execute the file in the current directory.